# How can I log into Facebook as a user from an iPhone app so I can post to their wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app that must send a game score to someone's Facebook wall, but I don't know how to sign them in from the app.

Can you sign into facebook using only url parameters or PHP code? Something like:  `http://facebook.com?login=**myusername**&password=**thepass**` using GET OR POST. If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. To post to a user's wall on Facebook, you'll need to have them install an app you write with the [`publish_stream` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/), and then you can use the [`scores` endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/score/) to publish those scores.

Comment: When you say instal app, from my Iphone app or from the web??.. explain more please

Comment: They can install it from their iPhone directly using [the iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). Once you've done that, you then have an access token that you can use to `POST` to the Graph API.

Answer (score 1):

No, Facebook would have never coded this as it is quite the security vulnerability for brute forcing users' passwords.

You should take a look at the [Facebook API.](http://developers.facebook.com/)

Comment: But they made it possible in xbox and many places.. and some iphone apps offer it, there most be a way..

Comment: Yes, but you cannot just sign in from a URL. Look at the Facebook API, that's how the Xbox and iPhone developers did it.

Comment: The Xbox and iPhone are special cases, the Xbox in particular, because Facebook allows non-browser endpoints to process user login details before giving those endpoints access to the API. In the vast majority of cases, you're either using a browser endpoint or a special SDK (like the iPhone).

Comment: I'm making the app for Iphone, but its pure C++... so how can that be done

Comment: well if its pure c++ why did you tag your question php and javascript?

Comment: [This is their iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk), it's written in Objective-C, but I imagine you should be able to link to it or use it somehow.

Comment: @Chris James Champeau, because the coding lang. i was asking for was more browser based, nothing C++ about it..